# Create java resources webapp folder structure with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, archetypes

I want to create `/java`, `/resources`, and  `/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` folder structure under `src`.

I have used the `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp` but it creates `/resources /webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` but doesn't create `/java` folder.

So in spite of creating the folder `/java` in eclipse manually is there any other way to create with some `-DarchetypeArtifactId=` so that it creates the above folder structure.

I'll be thankful if someone can tell me how can I customize and design my folder structure and create it with maven without using existing template.

Answer (score 3):

When you use -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp, java folder wont be created. It needs to be created manually.

It created the following structure

```
src
└── main
    └── resources
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 2):

Best choice is to follow Maven standard directory layout:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Archetypes are minimized due different programming languages can be used for web development:

[http://cvs.peopleware.be/training/maven/maven2/standardDirLayout.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110723201350/http://cvs.peopleware.be/training/maven/maven2/standardDirLayout.html) (link goes to web.archive since the main link is dead)

It will minimize configuration of plugins and also will simplify understanding and maintenance of Maven projects

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Maven Webapp using following archetype

```
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

which will automatically creates the desired folder structure

in your case its apart from `src\main\java`

```
src\main\resources
src\main\webapp
```